# Open pdf file url which is stored in Firebase storage

Tags: android, pdf, firebase, firebase-storage

I have uploaded a Pdf file to firebase storage, after uploading the pdf file to firebase storage, I am getting the download url. Now I want to open the pdf file from this download url in my application.

Below is the url I am getting after uploading the pdf file to firebase storage.

> https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/realtime-chat-46f4c.appspot.com/o/documents%2Fbf307aa5-79ae-4532-8128-ee394537b357.pdf?alt=media&token=2d0c5329-4717-4adc-9418-6614913e5bfa

Now I want to open an intent to view this pdf file, I've used the below code for this :

```
String url = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/realtime-chat-46f4c.appspot.com/o/documents%2Fbf307aa5-79ae-4532-8128-ee394537b357.pdf?alt=media&token=2d0c5329-4717-4adc-9418-6614913e5bfa";

Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "application/pdf");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose an Application:"));
```

My phone is having applications which can open this pdf file, still it says there are no applications installed to view this file.

If I convert this url in File and use the below code, then the chooser of applications get opened but it gives error that the file can't be opened.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File file = new File(name);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "aplication/pdf");
```

I've seen many answers that says first download the file and then open it, but I don't want to download the file, I just want to view it.

Please help me if anyone have any idea about this.

Thanks a lot in advanced.

Comment: When you say "it gives error that the file can't be opened", could you be a lot more specific about that?  Are you seeing this in some logs?  Please show exactly what you're seeing.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the Intent Chooser

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "application/pdf");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
Intent newIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open File");
try {
    startActivity(newIntent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    // Instruct the user to install a PDF reader here, or something
}
```

Comment: I've already tried this, but it doesn't open the Intent chooser and says there are no applications install to read this, but I have installed Pdf reader in my device.

Answer (score 2):

Your phone is not detecting the PDF because the URL you are using is a String object and not a PDF object. Technically, it should never open from the phone as PDF unless you download the PDF. PDF viewers on a phone only get activated once the Android OS tells them that it has a valid PDF file. Please take a look at source code of any of the PDF libraries to understand this better -> https://android-arsenal.com/tag/72?sort=created

However, to answer your problem, you should try opening your URL as a URL. It will activate the browser on your phone which in turn will detect that it needs a PDF reader and will activate the appropriate reader.

Something like

```
String url = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/realtime-chat-46f4c.appspot.com/o/documents%2Fbf307aa5-79ae-4532-8128-ee394537b357.pdf?alt=media&token=2d0c5329-4717-4adc-9418-6614913e5bfa";


public void openWebPage(String url) {
    Uri webpage = Uri.parse(url);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webpage);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

However, I am thinking that you want to just validate if the file got uploaded successfully. And if there is a local copy on the phone then just open the local copy instead of downloading another copy. If that is the case, then I recommend using file metadata to achieve that. Something like:

```
 // Create file metadata including the content type
StorageMetadata metadata = new StorageMetadata.Builder()
        .setCustomMetadata("myPDFfile", "localPDFfileName")
        .build();

// Upload the file and metadata
uploadTask = storageRef.child("pdf/localPDFfileName.pdf").putFile(file, metadata);
```

And on your success listener, retrieve the file metadata. If it is downloaded and looks complete, then open the PDF from your local phone storage. If not, then try downloading from the downloadURL as I mention at the start of the post. That should cover the validations you are trying to do.

Do elaborate more if I did not understand your problem, correctly. I will pick it up and amend my reply accordingly.

Comment: "**Now I want to open an intent to view this pdf file**" We are looking to preview the pdf file, not downloading it.

Comment: @KarloA.López - Yes, I understood that. But a PDF on a server cannot be previewed without downloading content. Hence, my suggestion to use Metadata.

Comment: At the end this is what I did, download the PDF to temp file and display with [PDF viewer](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer), I was looking for a simpler solution, its a shame that `http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=` does not work with firebase pdf document.

Comment: @KarloA.López - Like I mentioned, the simpler solution would be to match the key meta data between the uploaded file and the local file. For embedded reader function like GoogleDrive, you can try writing Firebase Functions - code on the server side. It can create a preview image of your uploaded file and you can display that image using webview in your app. Same technique as google drive

Answer (score 1):

**Please add following files/method to your project**

1. PdfDownloader.java
2. PDFDownloaderAsyncTask.java

and then using following method **handleViewPdf** to view pdf:

```
private void handleViewPdf () {

    File folder = getAppDirectory(context);
    String fileName = "test.pdf";// getPdfFileName(pdfUrl);
    File pdfFile = new File(folder, fileName);

    if (pdfFile.exists () && pdfFile.length () > 0) {
        openPDFFile (context, Uri.fromFile(pdfFile));
    }
    else {
        if (pdfFile.length () == 0) {
            pdfFile.delete ();
        }
        try {
            pdfFile.createNewFile ();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
        ArrayList<String> fileNameAndURL = new ArrayList<> ();
        fileNameAndURL.add (pdfFile.toString ());
        fileNameAndURL.add (pdfUrl);
        fileNameAndURL.add (fileName);
        if (pdfDownloaderAsyncTask == null) {
            pdfDownloaderAsyncTask = new PDFDownloaderAsyncTask (context, pdfFile);
        }
        if (hasInternetConnection (context)) {
            if (!pdfDownloaderAsyncTask.isDownloadingPdf ()) {
                pdfDownloaderAsyncTask = new PDFDownloaderAsyncTask (context, pdfFile);
                pdfDownloaderAsyncTask.execute (fileNameAndURL);
            }
        }
        else {
            //show error
        }
    }
}
```

**PDFDownloaderAsyncTask.java**

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.text.TextUtils;
    import android.widget.Toast;


    public class PDFDownloaderAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<String>, Void, String> {

        private boolean isDownloadingPdf = false;

        private File    file;
        private Context context;

        public PDFDownloaderAsyncTask (Context context, File file) {

            this.file = file;
            this.context = context;
            this.isDownloadingPdf = false;
        }

        public boolean isDownloadingPdf () {

            return this.isDownloadingPdf;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute () {

            super.onPreExecute ();
            //show loader etc
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground (ArrayList<String>... params) {

            isDownloadingPdf = true;
            File file = new File (params[0].get (0));
            String fileStatus = PdfDownloader.downloadFile (params[0].get (1), file);
            return fileStatus;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute (String result) {

            super.onPostExecute (result);
            Loader.hideLoader ();
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty (result) && result.equalsIgnoreCase (context.getString (R.string.txt_success))) {
                showPdf ();
            }
            else {
                isDownloadingPdf = false;
                Toast.makeText (context, context.getString (R.string.error_could_not_download_pdf), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();
                file.delete ();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled () {

            isDownloadingPdf = false;
            super.onCancelled ();
            //Loader.hideLoader ();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled (String s) {

            isDownloadingPdf = false;
            super.onCancelled (s);
            //Loader.hideLoader ();
        }

        private void showPdf () {

            new Handler ().postDelayed (new Runnable () {
                @Override
                public void run () {

                    isDownloadingPdf = false;
                    openPDFFile (context, Uri.fromFile (file));
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
```

**PdfDownloader.java**

```
package com.pdf;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class PdfDownloader {
    private static final int MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;

    public static String downloadFile (String fileUrl, File directory) {

        String downloadStatus;
        try {

            URL url = new URL (fileUrl);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection ();
            urlConnection.connect ();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream ();
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream (directory);
            int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength ();

            Log.d ("PDF", "Total size: " + totalSize);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[MEGABYTE];
            int bufferLength = 0;
            while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read (buffer)) > 0) {
                fileOutputStream.write (buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            }
            downloadStatus = "success";
            fileOutputStream.close ();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            downloadStatus = "FileNotFoundException";
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            downloadStatus = "MalformedURLException";
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            downloadStatus = "IOException";
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
        Log.d ("PDF", "Download Status: " + downloadStatus);
        return downloadStatus;
    }


    public static void openPDFFile (Context context, Uri path) {

        Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType (path, "application/pdf");
        intent.setFlags (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        try {
            context.startActivity (intent);
        }
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText (context, context.getString (R.string.txt_no_pdf_available), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
        }
        Loader.hideLoader ();
    }

    public static File getAppDirectory (Context context) {

        String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory ().toString ();
        File folder = new File (extStorageDirectory, context.getString (R.string.app_folder_name).trim ());
        if (!folder.exists ()) {
            boolean success = folder.mkdirs();
            Log.d ("Directory", "mkdirs():" + success);
        }
        return folder;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but I don't want to download the file, as I am uploading it from my device and it already exists on my device storage, but after uploading to firebase storage, I want to open it using the storage url.

Comment: <string name="txt_success">success</string>

Comment: PdfDownloader .downloadFile return "success"

Comment: This is just a check whether pdf was downloaded successfully or not.

Comment: I am getting a MalformedURLException. The url I am passing is of the form gs://<bucket>/<folder>/<filename> from firebase storage

Comment: I solved it. I just had to get the downloadURL from firebase and then pass it as the url.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to open the saved pdf file in your application rather than creating a intent to open in other application, you can use the following library to create the PdfView in Xml file. [AndroidPdfViewer](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer) (this library also provides the zoom in-out facility)

After that as mentioned in the [Firebase Document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_in_memory) use the saved path reference of the file location in firebase Storage to fetch the file in Bytes and add it to your PdfView as

For example your file path will be like : "/folder1/yourfile.pdf"

```
pdfView = (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
mFirebaseStorage=FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;

mFirebaseStorage.child("YourSavedFilePathRef").getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
 pdfView.fromBytes(bytes).load();
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"download unsuccessful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple code :)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    
Uri fileuri =  Uri.parse("URL of file on storage") ;
intent.setDataAndType(fileuri,"application/pdf");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
Intent in = Intent.createChooser(intent,"open file");
in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(in);
```

Hope this works :)

Answer (score -2):

try to encode your firebase database file url. it work with me

Answer (score -4):

Use Webview for view pdf file-

```
 WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    String pdf = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/realtime-chat-46f4c.appspot.com/o/documents%2Fbf307aa5-79ae-4532-8128-ee394537b357.pdf?alt=media&token=2d0c5329-4717-4adc-9418-6614913e5bfa";
    webview.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);
```

Comment: This is an option, but I don't want to view the pdf file in Webview. My requirement is to open the pdf file using intent in installed pdf viewers. Please help how can I achieve this. Thanks

Comment: Have you even tried this? This way of loading remote PDF with google pdf viewer doesn't even work, it says "No preview available".